# Process with multiple threads on multiprocessor system. How do they work?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

So I was reading about Processes and Threads and I had a question. Following is the scenario.

**Uniprocessor Environment**

I understand that the OS rotates the processes over processor for a particular time period.(quantum) . Now I get it when the process is single threaded, ie just one path of execution. In that case, whenever it is assigned the processor, it continues with it's execution. Let's say the process forks and or just creates a new thread. Now how does the entire process works? Is it that the OS will say to process P "Go on, continue with execution" and the Process within itself will pick the new thread or the parent thread on rotation? So that if there are more than two threads, the rotation seems fair to each thread. Or does the OS actually interacts with the threads? (In that case I am not sure what happens).

**Multiprocessor Environment**

Now say I have a multiprocessor environment. Now in this case, if there was just uni-threaded process, then OS will assign either of the processors to it and on it will go with it's execution. Now say, there are multiple threads in the Process. Now if I assign one of the processor to the process, and ask it to continue it's execution, and the Process has to pick either of the thread for it's execution, then there never will be parallel processing going on in that specific process. Since the process will have to put either of it's threads on the processor.

So how does it happen in both the cases?

Cheers.

Comment: This question is way too broad for the SO format. You should spend a little time with your favorite search engine looking up operating system scheduling. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)). See http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html for info on Linux scheduling. For Windows, see [About processes and threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx), especially the section about scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Process Scheduing

Operating Systems ultimately control these types of thread scheduling.

Windows systems are priority-based and so will allow a process to consume more resources that others. This is why your machine can 'hang', if a process has been escalated to a high priority. Priorities are ranged between 1-31 as far as I know.

Mac OS / Linux / Unix are time-based, allowing all processes to have equal amounts of CPU time. Therefore loading more processes will slow your system down as they all share a smaller slice of execution time.

## Uniprocessor Environment

The OS is ultimately responsible for this but switching processes involves (I cannot guarantee accuracy here, but its just an indication):

- Halting a process / thread
- Storing the current stack (code location)
- Storing the current registers of the CPU
- Asking the kernel for the next process/thread to run
- Kernel indicates which one has to be run
- OS reloads the registers from the cache
- OS reloads the current stack for the next application.
- Resumes the process

Obviously the more threads and processes you have running, the slower it will become. The problem is that the time taken to switch processes can actually take longer than the time allowed to execute the process.

Threads are just child processes of a single process. For a single processor, it just looks like additional work.

## Multi-processor Environment

Multi-processor environments work differently as the cache is shared amongst processors. I believe these are called L1 (Level) and L2 caches. So the difference is that processor A can reload the state stored by processor B without conflicts. 'Hyper-threading' also has the same approach, although this is processor specific. The difference here is that a processor could solely control a specific process - this is called 'CPU Affinity' Its not encouraged for every process, but it does allow an application to have a dedicated processor to work off.

Comment: Linux is also priority-based: "All scheduling is preemptive: if a thread with a higher static priority becomes ready to run, the currently running thread will be preempted and returned to the wait list for its static priority level.  The scheduling policy determines the ordering only within the list of runnable threads with equal static priority." http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man2/sched_getscheduler.2.html

Comment: @DarkFalcon - thanks for clarifying. I'm a Windows guy. I remember the 2 types from University, so maybe its just Unix based systems that work in a time-based manner?

Comment: Don't know. I just know this much from dealing with priority inversion issues on an embedded system recently. Pretty amazing how a low priority thread can block a real-time thread just by holding a lock for 5 seconds even through the low-priority thread is not blocking on anything. It just didn't get rescheduled. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is OS-specific, of course, but most operating systems schedule at the thread level. A process is just a grouping of threads. For example, on Linux, threads are called "tasks" and each is scheduled independently. They are created with the `clone` call. What is typically called a thread is a task which shares its address space (and other resources such as file descriptors, mount points, etc.) with the creating task. Note that the `clone` call can also create what is typically called a process if the flags to enable sharing are not passed.

Considering the above, any thread may be scheduled at any time on any processor, no matter how many processors there are available. That said, most OSs also attempt to maintain some measure of processor affinity to avoid excessive cache misses, but usually if a thread is runnable and a different CPU is available, it will change CPUs. Often there is also a way to specify which CPUs a particular thread may execute upon.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter whether there is 1 or 128 processors.  The OS manages access to resources to try an efficiently match up requests with availabilty, and that includes CPU execution.  If a thread is running, it has already managed to get some CPU but, if it requests a resource that is not immediately available, it no longer needs any CPU until that other resource does become free, and so the OS will remove CPU execution from it and, if there is another thread that is waiting for CPU, it will hand it over.  When the requested reource does become available, the thread will be made ready again.  If there is a core free, it will be made running 'immediately', if not, the CPU scheduling algorithm makes a decision on whether to stop a currently-running thread to free up a core or to leave the newly-ready thrad waiting.

It's better to try and ignore things like 'time-slice, quantum, priority' - it causes much confusion and FUD.  If a running thread wants something it cannot have yet, it doesn't need any more CPU cycles, and the OS will take them away and, if another thread needs it, apply them there.  That is why preemptive multitaskers exist - to match up threads with resources in an attempt to maximize forward progress.